# Python Requests hanging/freezing

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using the requests library to get a lot of webpages from somewhere. He's the pertinent code:

```
response = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=.1)
response.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
response = response.get(url)
```

After a while it just hangs/freezes (never on the same webpage) while getting the page. Here's the traceback when I interrupt it:

```
File "/Users/Student/Hockey/Scrape/html_pbp.py", line 21, in get_pbp
  response = r.read().decode('utf-8')
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 456, in read
  return self._readall_chunked()
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 566, in _readall_chunked
  value.append(self._safe_read(chunk_left))
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 612, in _safe_read
  chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
  return self._sock.recv_into(b)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Does anybody know what could be causing it? Or (more importantly) does anybody know a way to stop it if it takes more than a certain amount of time so that I could try again?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Seems like setting a (read) [timeout](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts) might help you.

Something along the lines of:

```
response = response.get(url, timeout=5)
```

(This will set both connect and read timeout to 5 seconds.)

In `requests`, unfortunately, neither *connect* nor *read* timeouts are set by default, even though the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts) say it's good to set it:

> Most requests to external servers **should have a timeout attached**, in case the server is not responding in a timely manner. By default, requests do not time out unless a timeout value is set explicitly. Without a timeout, your code may hang for minutes or more.

Just for completeness, the **connect timeout** is the number of seconds `requests` will wait for your client to establish a connection to a remote machine, and the **read timeout** is the number of seconds the client will wait between bytes sent from the server.

Comment: if i was checking through a list of URLs and one of them timed out, how would i carry on through the list after the time out?

Comment: oscar dolloway You could catch the timeout exception and just continue with your list.

Comment: This helped me today! saved me so much grief with a hang randomly occuring when loading json from a string from a request call!

Answer (score 4):

Patching the documented "send" function will fix this for all requests - even in many dependent libraries and sdk's.  When patching libs, be sure to patch supported/documented functions, otherwise you may wind up silently losing the effect of your patch.

```
import requests

DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 180

old_send = requests.Session.send

def new_send(*args, **kwargs):
     if kwargs.get("timeout", None) is None:
         kwargs["timeout"] = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
     return old_send(*args, **kwargs)

requests.Session.send = new_send
```

The effects of not having any timeout are quite severe, and the use of a default timeout can almost never break anything - because TCP itself has timeouts as well.

On Windows the default TCP timeout is 240 seconds, TCP RFC recommend a minimum of 100 seconds for RTO*retry.  Somewhere in that range is a safe default.

Comment: from the userland perspective tcp doesn't have timeouts. Most operating systems implement a connection timeout though, but once the connection has been established, there will be no "read" timeout unless one of the participating applications implements it.

Comment: @hek2mgl yep.  here's a good article on it:  https://blog.cloudflare.com/when-tcp-sockets-refuse-to-die/.   most flavors of linux will have timeouts (keepalive, etc) on by default.   without them, the results are even worse.   On windows, FWICT, there's no way to disable the TCP keepalive... it just drops connections after 240 seconds of inactivity - during a read or otherwise.

Comment: I just yesterday saw (for a different reason) that Ubuntu has indeed tcp keep alives enabled by default. I just remember a few years ago a debug session on Debian where it was not enabled (by default?) ... We've also used this as part of an application once, where we interfaced a serial rs232 application (hotel billing system) with tcp via socat. This was basically a simulated cable, no timeouts wanted.

Answer (score 1):

To set timeout globally instead of specifying in every request:

```
from requests.adapters import TimeoutSauce

REQUESTS_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = float(os.getenv("REQUESTS_TIMEOUT_SECONDS", 5))

class CustomTimeout(TimeoutSauce):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs["connect"] is None:
            kwargs["connect"] = REQUESTS_TIMEOUT_SECONDS
        if kwargs["read"] is None:
            kwargs["read"] = REQUESTS_TIMEOUT_SECONDS
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


# Set it globally, instead of specifying ``timeout=..`` kwarg on each call.
requests.adapters.TimeoutSauce = CustomTimeout


sess = requests.Session()
sess.get(...)
sess.post(...)
```

Comment: Patching the `send` function is better, because it's a documented public api.   Patching TimeoutSauce isn't supported.